# Does sitting idle for one month without work leads to depression?

Tags: depression

Does sitting idle for one month without work leads to depression?

Following case is an example:

If a human do 8 hours job before Computer. Because of no work or a few work; generally sitting idle for one month. and when work came after a month; then that human do not want to do it because:

Symptoms which generally such human is facing:

1) that humans head remain heavy; always feel like outing. Even if that human go to outing and come back to office feel like go out again.

2) It is like nothing is in that human head. Just sounds "shaaan shaaaan".

3) Sometimes it is like that human need to get my ear clean from ENT; may be due to that head is heavy. but nothing is there in that human's ear , because that human use to clean my ears during bathing.

4) Life becoming dull. Now work came after 1 month; that human being lazy not to attempt that work. that human do not want work now.

5) Not agreeing to any external Motivation and self motivation is becoming zero.

6) Just looking at Facebook, Amazon and doing nothing. Not a like on facebook; but looking just. It is like NOTHING NEW.

7) if reading news forget the story after 15 minutes. Forget the work that human's family member says.

8) that human feel like that human is blunder; that human do mistakes; you all leave that human; throw that human out of computer company.

Could anyone please figure out situation of that human's mind!!! is that human getting mad or depressed?

Comment: feel free to ask a more general scientific question about the effects of unemployment on depression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two answers:
The first, and most important one: do not ask any online forum whether you are getting depressed, since usually there will be many opinions about your situation from people who are not qualified in the field, be it psychiatry or psychotherapy. Please: if you do not feel well, and if your current situation is worrying you, seek help from your general physician or better if accessible to you a psychotherapist/ a psychiatrist with whom you can talk personally. There is no shame in seeking help from these persons, and in case you find out together with them that you truly need some kind of help, they will know ways of help that are based on evidence from empirical research and likely better and better fitting to your individual situation than suggestions on the internet.

Second: Your question's title implicitly asks whether sitting one month without work in front of a computer *always* leads to depression. It might and it might not depending on many factors (such as coping strategies with gratification crises, previous episodes of depressive disorders, social support, and many more, which differ from person to person). The danger of answers to a question stated like this is that yes-answers might lead you to think you are depressed, even though you are not, or no-answers lead you to think you aren't depressed even though you might need help. This is to say, the danger is to mistake such an answer for a diagnosis, which are two *completely different* things. A diagnosis needs to be done by a person qualified to do this, such as psychotherapists or psyhiatrists. They, too, will know further steps in case a diagnosis is given.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. I am updating question to more general.